# Operations on canavs image in js frozen browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote js script which performs various operations (eg. summing up photos with a constant, square root, moving, applying filters) on the pictures in the canvas. But for large images (eg. 2000x200 pixels), the script frozen/crashes the browser (tested on Firefox), in addition, everything takes a long time.

```
function get_pixel (x, y, canvas)
{
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
    return imgData.data;
}

function set_pixel (x, y, canvas, red, green, blue, alpha)
{ 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height), 
    pxData = imgData.data, 
    length = pxData.length; 

    var i = (x + y * canvas.width) * 4;
    pxData[i] = red; 
    pxData[i + 1] = green; 
    pxData[i + 2] = blue; 
    pxData[i + 3] = alpha;                               
    ctx.putImageData (imgData, 0, 0);                         
}

function sum (number, canvas1, canvas2)
{
    show_button_normalization (false);

    asyncLoop(
    {
        length : 5,
        functionToLoop : function(loop, i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                asyncLoop(
                {
                    length : 5,
                    functionToLoop : function(loop, i){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var pixel1 = get_pixel (i, j, canvas1);
                            var pixel2;

                            if (canvas2 != null)
                            {
                                pixel2 = get_pixel (i, j, canvas2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pixel2 = new Array(4);
                                pixel2[0] = number;
                                pixel2[1] = number;
                                pixel2[2] = number;
                                pixel2[3] = number;
                            }

                            var pixel = new Array(4);
                            pixel[0] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[0]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[0]*0.5));
                            pixel[1] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[1]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[1]*0.5));
                            pixel[2] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[2]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[2]*0.5));
                            pixel[3] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[3]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[3]*0.5));

                            set_pixel (i, j, image1_a, pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);
                            loop();
                        },1000);
                    },   
                });
                loop();
            },1000);
        },   
    });



    /*for (var i=0; i<canvas1.width; i++)
    {
        for (var j=0; j<canvas1.height; j++)
        {
            var pixel1 = get_pixel (i, j, canvas1);
            var pixel2;

            if (canvas2 != null)
            {
                pixel2 = get_pixel (i, j, canvas2);
            }
            else
            {
                pixel2 = new Array(4);
                pixel2[0] = number;
                pixel2[1] = number;
                pixel2[2] = number;
                pixel2[3] = number;
            }

            var pixel = new Array(4);
            pixel[0] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[0]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[0]*0.5));
            pixel[1] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[1]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[1]*0.5));
            pixel[2] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[2]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[2]*0.5));
            pixel[3] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[3]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[3]*0.5));

            set_pixel (i, j, image1_a, pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);
        }
    }*/
}
```

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the commented code relevant to the question? If not you should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Process pixels together!!

Looking at the code I would say that Firefox crashing and/or taking a long time is not a surprise at all. An image that is 2000 by 2000 pixels has 4 million pixels. I don't know what `asyncLoop` does but to me it looks like you are using timers to set groups of 5 pixels at a time. This is horrifically inefficient.

#### Problems with your code

Even looking at the commented code (which I assume is an alternative approch) you are processing the pixels with way to much overhead.

The array `pixel` you get from the function `getPixel` which returns the pixel array that is part of the object `getImageData` returns. If you look at the details of [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and te return object [imageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) you will see that the array is a typed array of type `Uint8ClampedArray`

That means most of the code you use to mix the pixels is redundant as that is done by javascript automatically when it assigns a number to any typed array.

```
pixel[0] = parseInt (parseInt (pixel1[0]*0.5) + parseInt (pixel2[0]*0.5));
```

Will be much quicker if you use

```
pixel[0] = (pixel1[0] + pixel2[0]) * 0.5; // a * n + b * n is the same as ( a+ b) *n
                                          // with one less multiplication.
```

#### Standard simple image processing

But even then using a function call for each pixel adds a massive overhead to the basic operation you are performing. You should fetch all the pixels in one go and process them as two flat arrays.

Your sum function should look more like

```
function sum (number, canvas1, canvas2){
    var i, data, ctx, imgData, imgData1, data1;
    ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
    data = imgData.data; // get the array of pixels
    if(canvas2 === null){             
         i = data.length;
         number *= 0.5;  // pre calculate number
         while(i-- > 0){
              data[i] = data[i] * 0.5 + number;
         }
    }else{
         if(canvas1.width !== canvas2.width || canvas1.height !== canvas2.height){
              throw new RangeError("Canvas size miss-match, can not process data as requested.");
         }
         data1 = canvas2.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas2.width, canvas2.height).data
         i = data.length;
         while(i-- > 0){
              data[i] = (data[i] + data1[i]) * 0.5;
         }
     }
     ctx.setImageData(imgData,0,0); // put the new pixels back to the canvas
 }
```

#### Bit math is quicker

You can improve on that if you use a bit of bit manipulation. Using a 32 bit typed array you can divide then add four 8 bit values in parallel (4* approx quicker for pixel calculations).

- > **Note** that this method will round down by one value a little more often than it should. ie `Math.floor(199 * 233) === 216` is true while the method below will return 215. This can be corrected for by using the bottom bit of both inputs to add to the result. This completely eliminates the rounding error but the processing cost in my view is not worth the improvement. I have included the fix as commented code.
- > **Note** this method will only work for `a / n + b / m` where `n` and `m` are equal to `2^p` and `p` is an integer > 0 and < 7 (in other words only if `n` and `m` are 2,4,8,16,32,64,127) and you must mask out the bottom `p` bits for `a` and `b`

Example performs `C = C * 0.5 + C1 * 0.5` when `C` and `C1` represent each R,G,B,A channel for `canvas1` and `canvas2`

```
function sum (number, canvas1, canvas2){
    var i, data, ctx, imgData, data32, data32A;
    // this number is used to remove the bottom bit of each color channel
    // The bottom bit is redundant as divide by 2 removes it
    const botBitMask = 0b11111110111111101111111011111110;
    // mask for rounding error (not used in this example)
    // const botBitMaskA = 0b00000001000000010000000100000001;
    ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
    data32 = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);
    i = data32.length;  // get the length that is 1/4 the size
    if(canvas2 === null){             
         number >>= 1;  // divide by 2
         // fill to the 4 channels RGBA
         number = (number << 24) + (number << 16) + (number << 8) + number; 
         // get reference to the 32bit version of the pixel data 
         while(i-- > 0){
              // Remove bottom bit of each channel and then divide each channel by 2 using zero fill right shift (>>>) then add to number
              data32[i] = ((data32[i] & botBitMask) >>> 1) + number;
         }
    }else{
         if(canvas1.width !== canvas2.width || canvas1.height !== canvas2.height){
              throw new RangeError("Canvas size miss-match, can not process data as requested.");
         }
         data32A = new Uint32Array(canvas2.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas2.width, canvas2.height).data.buffer);

         i = data32.length;
         while(i-- > 0){
              // for fixing rounding error include the following line removing the second one. Do the same for the above loop but optimise for number 
              // data32[i] = (((data32[i] & botBitMask) >>> 1) + ((data32A[i] & botBitMask) >>> 1)) | ((data32[i] & botBitMaskA) | (data32A[i] & botBitMaskA))
              data32[i] = ((data32[i] & botBitMask) >>> 1) + ((data32A[i] & botBitMask) >>> 1);
         }
     }
     ctx.setImageData(imgData,0,0); // put the new pixels back to the canvas
 }
```

With all that you should not have any major problems. Though you will still have the page blocked while the image is being processed (depending on the machine and the image size it may take up to a second or 2)

#### Other solutions.

If you want to stop the image processing from blocking the page you can use a web worker and just send the data to them to process synchronously. You can find out how to do that but just searching  stackOverflow.

Or use WebGL to process the images.

And you have one final option. The canvas api uses the GPU to do all its rendering and if you understand the way [blending and compositing](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#canvascompositingandblending) works you can do a surprising amount of maths using the canvas.

For example you can multiply all pixels RGBA channels with a value 0-1 using the following.

```
// multiplies all channels in source canvas by val and returns the resulting canvas
// returns the can2 the result of each pixel
// R *= val;
// G *= val;
// B *= val;
// A *= val;

function multiplyPixels(val, source)
    var sctx = source.getContext("2d");

    // need two working canvas. I create them here but if you are doing this
    // many times you should create them once and reuse them
    var can1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    var can2 = document.createElement("canvas");
    can1.width = can2.width = source.width;
    can1.height= can2.height = source.height;

    var ctx1 = can1.getContext("2d");
    var ctx2 = can2.getContext("2d");

    var chanMult = Math.round(255 * val);
    // clamp it to 0-255 inclusive
    chanMult = chanMult < 0 ? 0 : chanMult > 255 ? 255 : chanMult;

    ctx1.drawImage(source,0,0); // copy the source

    // multiply all RGB pixels by val
    ctx1.fillStyle = "rgba(" + chanMult + "," + chanMult + "," + chanMult + ",1)";
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, source.width, source.height);

    // now multiply the alpha channel by val. Clamp it to 0-1
    ctx2.globalAlpha = val < 0 ? 0 : val > 1 ? 1 : val;
    ctx2.drawImage(can1,0,0);

    return can2;
}
```

There are quite a few [composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) that you can use in combination to do multiplication, addition, subtraction and division. Note though the accuracy is a little less than 8bits as addition and subtraction requires weighted values to compensate for the blending's (automatic) multiplication. Also the alpha channel must be handled separately from the RGB channels using `globalAlpha` and the compositing operations.

#### Realtime

The processing you are doing is very simple and a 2000 by 2000 pixel image can easily be processed in realtime. [WebGl filter](http://evanw.github.io/webgl-filter/) is an example of using webGL to do image processing. Though the filter system is not modular and the code is very old school it is a good backbone for webGL filters and offers much higher quality results because it uses floating point RGBA values.